# Using cyclotomic polynomials to show a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I have been given the polynomial $$f(x)=x^8+x^7-x^5-x^4-x^3+x+1$$ and have been asked to show it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by considering the product $(x^2-x+1)f$. (Looking it up, I realise $f$ is in fact a cyclotomic polynomial itself (it's $\Phi_{30}$) so is irreducible straight away, but I can't just quote this - I am allowed to use the general fact that cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but have to actually prove it is cyclotomic before applying this).

---

My attempt so far:
$x^2-x+1$ is the 6th cyclotomic polynomial, and can be written $(x-e^{\pi i/3})(x-e^{-\pi i/3})$ and is itself irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. The product $(x^2-x+1)f$ turns out to be $$x^{10}-x^5+1=\Phi_6(x^5)$$ but I am unsure what the next step is here - it seems important that this is effectively the same cyclotomic polynomial in a different variable. How is considering the product $(x^2-x+1)f$ meant to help?

Comment: It would help to say *which* cyclotomic polynomial that is: the 30th one.

Comment: @KCd have edited to indicate this, but cannot just quote that without proof and the question seems to want a different approach

Comment: I didn't mean you should put that in your homework solution, but just in your question above, as you did.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can also upvote any answer that you like. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. As you already know, $$x^{10}-x^5+1=(x^2-x+1)f(x)$$ Now, note that $$(e^{i\pi/15})^{10}-(e^{i\pi/15})^5+1=e^{2i\pi/3}-e^{i\pi/3}+1=e^{2i\pi/3}+e^{4i\pi/3}+1=0$$
Since $e^{i\pi/15}$ is a root of $x^{10}-x^5+1$, then it must be the root of at least one of the factors $x^2-x+1$ or $f(x)$. Note that $\Phi_{30}(x)$, the minimal polynomial of $e^{i\pi/15}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, is of degree $\varphi(30)=8$, so $e^{i\pi/15}$ is not a root of $x^2-x+1$, which means that $e^{i\pi/15}$ must be a root of $f(x)$. Since $\Phi_{30}(x)$ is the unique monic minimal polynomial of $e^{i\pi/15}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the fact that $e^{i\pi/15}$ is a root of $f(x)$ and $\deg(f)=\deg(\Phi_{30})$ implies that $f(x)=\Phi_{30}(x)$. Finally, since $f(x)$ is cyclotomic, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a primitive $30$th root of unity then $x^5$ is a primitive $6$th root of unity. This means $\Phi_{30}(x)$ divides $\Phi_6(x^5)$. Because $\Phi_{30}$ is irreducible and $\deg\Phi_{30}=\varphi(30)=8$ it follows that $f=\Phi_{30}$.